# Adding animation to scrolling background in Android

Tags: java, android, 2d-games

I've created 2 separate projects in Android from tutorials etc., - one which runs an animation of an horse running, and the other a scrolling background. Both work well - but because they implement separate Activities, how do I manage to run both inside one project?? ie the animation of the horse on the top of the scrolling background?
Here is my code for the separate projects:
**FrameAnimateActivity**

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class FrameAnimatedActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frame_animated);

        ImageView gyroView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gyro);
        //set the animation drawable as background
        gyroView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gyro_animation);
        //create an animation drawable using the background
        AnimationDrawable gyroAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) gyroView.getBackground();
        //start the animation
        gyroAnimation.start();

        ImageView img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gyro);

        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f);          //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
        animation.setDuration(5000);  // animation duration 
        animation.setRepeatCount(5);  // animation repeat count
        animation.setRepeatMode(2);   // repeat animation (left to right, right to left )
        //animation.setFillAfter(true);      

        img_animation.startAnimation(animation);  // start animation 

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.frame_animated, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And the code for the scrolling background:
**MainActivity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MovingBackGround(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**MovingBackground.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MovingBackGround extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private Bitmap backGround;

    public MovingBackGround(Context context) {
        super(context);
        backGround = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.ab);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        doDrawRunning(canvas);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    /**
     * Draws current state of the game Canvas.
     */

    private int mBGFarMoveX = 0;
    private int mBGNearMoveX = 0;

    private void doDrawRunning(Canvas canvas) {

        // decrement the far background
        mBGFarMoveX = mBGFarMoveX - 1;

        // decrement the near background
        mBGNearMoveX = mBGNearMoveX - 4;

        // calculate the wrap factor for matching image draw
        int newFarX = backGround.getWidth() - (-mBGFarMoveX);

        // if we have scrolled all the way, reset to start
        if (newFarX <= 0) {
            mBGFarMoveX = 0;
            // only need one draw
            canvas.drawBitmap(backGround, mBGFarMoveX, 0, null);

        } else {
            // need to draw original and wrap
            canvas.drawBitmap(backGround, mBGFarMoveX, 0, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(backGround, newFarX, 0, null);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Create a layout with includes the _MovingBackGround _ View and the Views present in _R.layout.activity_frame_animated_ (you may also just add a _MovingBackGround_ view xml-tag to the later mentioned layout). Create a project which includes the above _MovingBackGround_ view class and your above activity.

As it looks like you're not quite familiar with the concepts of Views and Activities, I suggest you reading the android documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: Sorry - not clear on order of new project - Should this be a MainActivity, with content Views of both FrameAnimatedActivity and MovingBackground classes??? Or another order?? Thanks!